# How to figure out if the first index in an array is a negative sign

Tags: c++, boolean, negative-number

I am trying to write a bool function that looks at the first index in an array which contains a positive or negative number and classifies if it is a negative sign (i.e. -). If it is a negative Sign it returns false everything else returns true. I am trying to figure out how to compare the negative sign. The following code give an error because of the '-'

```
    bool BigNum::get_positive() const
{
char '-';
if(digits[0] == '-')
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: what do you expect to achieve with this: `char '-';`?

Comment: There are some existing libraries for big integers [I assume that is what you are trying to do], why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Also, this is more of a style issue, but since your function is trying to determine whether an instance of BigNum represents a positive number, why not call it `isPositive()`? A function called `get_X()` usually suggests that it's returning some stored info, which is not the case here.

Comment: An additional style issue is the `if (condition) return true; else return false;`, which should logically be `return !condition;` (without the `if`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char '-';
```

The compiler thinks you're trying to declare a char, but that's not a valid declaration.

Your entire function could be replaced with:

```
return (digits[0] != '-');
```

Of course, this is assuming that `[0]` is a valid index of `digits`. If not, bad things will happen. If you know the length of the array, you can do a check like this:

```
if( digits_length < 1 )
  return false;
return (digits[0] != '-');
```

Comment: Wouldn't this better be written `return digits_length > 0 && digits[0] != '-'`?  (Supposing you want a result in this case: I suspect that throwing an exception, or even aborting, would be more appropriate.)

Comment: @James: well, if the string is 0 length then it doesn't start with a `-`, but it also doesn't represent a number. So it sort of depends how the function is intended to be used.

Comment: @Steve Yes.  As often occurs here, we're asked the best implementation of a function without being told what it should do.  Since there was some talk of "negative" (which only makes sense on a number), I assumed that this was a precondition, but the original poster really didn't specify.  Returning a value (an arbitrary `bool`, or an `enum`), throwing an exception, or aborting are all valid responses, depending on the exact specifications of the function.

Comment: @James: Agreed. Even UB might be reasonable, if as you say it's a precondition that the input be a valid representation of a number. I think I can generalize, people who can fully specify this function would know how to write it (a version that works, I mean, not necessarily agree on the most readable). An expert programmer with absolutely zero knowledge of C syntax might be an exception, but an expert would read a bit rather than ask this sort of question.

Answer (score 1):

you must delete or comment  "char '-';"

Answer (score 1):

Mistake lies in line char '-'. 
'-' is supposed to be stored in some variable which later could be used in *if* clause to compare. This is a syntactical error because you havn't defined a storage for '-'.

Otherwise as pointed above just delete this line and get away with using '-' in *if* (as you have already done it)